How to construct the nets using the coordinate projection on the cube?
I am reading a paper, but I don't quite understand how they construct the nets for a set. I hope someone can explain why this method works. I have previously encountered how to construct nets on a sphere.
Let $n>d>1$ be large enough integer. Define $n_0=[\frac{n\log d}{d}]$, $p=\sqrt{\frac{d}{\log d}}$, and $n_2=[n/d]$. Assume that $n_0=1$ (i.e., $\frac{d^2}{\log d}\ge n$). For a given vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\sigma=\sigma_x$ be a non increasing rearrangement of $\{|x_i|\}_{i=1}^n$ with $x_j^*=|x_{\sigma(j)}|$ for $1\le j\le n$ and $x_1^*\ge x_2^*\ge \dots \ge x_n^*$. Define
$$
T_1:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_1^*>d^{3/2} x^*_{n_2}\}
$$
and $T_1':=\{x\in T_1: x_1^*=1\}$.
For $x\in T_1'$, we set $B_2=\sigma_x([n_2])$ and $B_3=\sigma_x([n]\setminus [n_2])$, where $[n]:=\{1,2,3,\dots, n\}$.
I am confused about the following construction of $d^{-3/2}$ nets.

Fix $J_0\subset [n]$ with $|J_0|=n_2-1$, we construct a $d^{-3/2}$-net in the set
$$
T_{J_0}:=\{P_{n_2}x: x\in T_1', B_2=J_0, x_{n^2}=0\}
$$
where $P_{n_2}$ denote the coordinate projection on $\mathbb{R}^{n_2}$.


Since for $x\in T_1'$, we have $x_1^*\le 1$, it is enough to take $d^{-3/2}$-net $\mathcal{K}_{J_0}$ of cardinality at most
$$
(3d^{3/2})^{2|J_0|}
$$
in the coordinate projection of the cube $P_{J_0}(B_\infty^n)$.

Question: why the above argument holds?
